# Is it possible to pass the value of an Angular-generated input without an ID into a function?

Tags: angular, input

I'm trying to make the values of the cells in a column on a table editable. The problem is, since the table is dynamically generated using MatTableDataSource in Angular with values from an API, the cell elements can't have unique IDs. How can I make it so that on a blur (after editing and changing the value in a cell), it passes that value to a function that can then write that new value into a request to the API to update it?

Here's the HTML of the column of cells in question:

```html
<div>
  <table mat-table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" [dataSource]="sortedData">
<!-- Other columns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="maxInstalls">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Max Installs</th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let profile">
       <input type="number" min="0" value="{{profile.maximumInstalls}}"> <!-- I just need the value of this input -->
       </td>
      </ng-container>
<!-- Other columns -->
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;">
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
<input type="number" min="0" value="{{profile.maximumInstalls}}" (blur)="onBlu(profile)">
```

if you want the value of the input you need to create a reference to input and use it like below

```
<input #valueInput type="number" min="0" value="{{profile.maximumInstalls}}" (blur)="onBlur(valueInput.value)">
```

see the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffudch)

Comment: That only returns the object taken from the API, not the value of the input box itself. I need to know the value the user typed in before blurring their focus.

Comment: That reference made it work. Now I just have to figure out why it's sometimes marking it as an unused variable even though I use it in a function. But thanks! That answers this question.